# Using Service Broker with Sql Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server-express, service-broker

Is it possible to use external activation on sql express without going thru sql enterprise/standard?

I would like to send a message to sql express service broker, then have it notify my external application service running on the same box, in order to kick off a console app to pickup the message and process it. I do this already successfully from a remote Sql Enterprise db.

But now I need everything self contained on one box with Sql express, without using the remote Sql Enterprise.

However sql express has limitations so I'm wondering if I can use sql express as described in a stand alone configuration, without going thru Sql Enterprise. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that, as long as the box sending the message is non-express edition.

The edition-related limitation of Service Broker is that a message must go through at least one non-express instance on its way from the sending service to the receiving service. There are no limitations on the [External Activator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/11/21/announcing-service-broker-external-activator.aspx) service itself.

Comment: That's a real bummer. Will have to use the standard edition for my use case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: External activation will work with express.  The only reason you need standard or better is if you want to use routing or deliver to multiple SQL servers.  If the messages are being sent and received on different queues in the same database express will work fine.