# SqlDependency issue with the asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ext.net, sqldependency

I am trying get the changed values from the sqlserver using the server_broker feature.

my code is like below

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData2();

}
private void GetData2()
{
    List<Masa> lst = new List<Masa>();
    using (SqlConnection con = Baglan.Sql)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT [Id],[Ad],[Durum] FROM [dbo].[Masa]";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate);

            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Masa alt = new Masa
                    {
                        Ad = reader["Ad"].ToString(),
                        Id = reader["Id"].ToString(),
                        Durum = reader["Durum"].ToString()
                    };

                    lst.Add(alt);
                }

                gridMasa.GetStore().DataSource = lst;
                gridMasa.GetStore().DataBind();
            }


        }
    }


}

public void dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{   GetData2();
    SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;

    dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate);

}
```

when I check the the code via breakpoint which I make some changes on database,It can reach the method called dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate ,but I have no seen changes on  my datagrid.
where am I doing wrong??

my page source is as below:

```
 <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" ID="mymanager"></ext:ResourceManager>
<ext:GridPanel runat="server"  ID="gridMasa" Title="MASALAR" Height="580" Layout="FitLayout" Flex="1"
                        IDMode="Static">

                        <Store>
                            <ext:Store ID="strMasa" runat="server">

                                <Model>
                                    <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server">
                                        <Fields>
                                            <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                                            <ext:ModelField Name="Ad" />
                                            <ext:ModelField Name="Durum" />
                                        </Fields>
                                    </ext:Model>
                                </Model>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <Exception Handler="Ext.Msg.alert('Products - Load failed', operation.getError());" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:Store>
                        </Store>

                        <ColumnModel ID="ColumnMxodel1" Flex="1" runat="server">
                            <Columns>

                                <ext:RowNumbererColumn ID="Column5" runat="server" Text="Id" 
                                    >
                                </ext:RowNumbererColumn>

                                <ext:Column ID="KisxiId" runat="server" Hidden="true" Text="Id" DataIndex="Id" 
                                    Flex="1">
                                </ext:Column>
                                <ext:Column ID="Coluxmn2w" runat="server" Text="Masa Adı" Flex="1" Align="Center" DataIndex="Ad">

                                </ext:Column>
                                   <ext:Column ID="Column8" runat="server" Text="Durum" Flex="1" Align="Center" DataIndex="Durum">

                                </ext:Column>
                                      <ext:Column ID="Column11" Hidden="true" runat="server" Text="Durum" Flex="1" Align="Center" DataIndex="Durum">

                                </ext:Column>

                            </Columns>
                        </ColumnModel>
                        <SelectionModel>
                            <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="rowSelectioxnModel2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
                                <SelectedRows>
                                    <ext:SelectedRow RowIndex="0"></ext:SelectedRow>
                                </SelectedRows>


                            </ext:RowSelectionModel>
                        </SelectionModel>

                    </ext:GridPanel>
```

source code is as below:

> Ext.net.ResourceMgr.init({id:"mymanager",aspForm:"form1"});
>   Ext.onReady(function(){Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel",{store:{model:Ext.define("App.Model1",
>   {extend: "Ext.data.Model",
>   fields:[{name:"Id"},{name:"Ad"},{name:"Durum"}]
>   }),storeId:"strMasa",autoLoad:true,proxy:{data:[{"Id":"8","Ad":"44448989","Durum":"2"},{"Id":"9","Ad":"MASA
>   55i","Durum":"1"},{"Id":"12","Ad":"MASA
>   3","Durum":"1"},{"Id":"44","Ad":"MASA
>   4","Durum":"1"},{"Id":"45","Ad":"MASA
>   5","Durum":"1"},{"Id":"46","Ad":"MASA
>   6","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"47","Ad":"MASA
>   7","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"48","Ad":"MASA
>   8","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"49","Ad":"MASA
>   9","Durum":"1"},{"Id":"51","Ad":"MASA
>   10","Durum":"2"},{"Id":"52","Ad":"MASA
>   11","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"53","Ad":"MASA
>   12","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"54","Ad":"MASA
>   13","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"55","Ad":"MASA
>   14","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"56","Ad":"MASA
>   15","Durum":"-1"},{"Id":"57","Ad":"MASA 166","Durum":"-1"}], type:
>   'memory'},listeners:{exception:{fn:function(proxy,response,operation){Ext.Msg.alert('Products
>   - Load failed', operation.getError());}}}},id:"gridMasa",height:580,renderTo:"App.gridMasa_Container",flex:1,layout:"fit",title:"MASALAR",columns:{id:"ColumnMxodel1",flex:1,items:[{id:"Column5",xtype:"rownumberer",text:"Id"},{id:"KisxiId",hidden:true,flex:1,dataIndex:"Id",text:"Id"},{id:"Coluxmn2w",flex:1,align:"center",dataIndex:"Ad",text:"Masa
>   Adı"},{id:"Column8",flex:1,align:"center",dataIndex:"Durum",text:"Durum"},{id:"Column11",hidden:true,flex:1,align:"center",dataIndex:"Durum",text:"Durum"}]},selModel:window.App.rowSelectioxnModel2=Ext.create("Ext.selection.RowModel",{proxyId:"rowSelectioxnModel2",selType:"rowmodel",selectedData:[{rowIndex:0}]})});});

**update**

this  is how enable database(sql server express 2012) which triger every changes happened database.

```
alter database [Your database name here] set enable_broker with rollback immediate 
select name, is_broker_enabled from sys.databases
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you call the GetData2 method?

Comment: inside the dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate method which is trigger any changes on sql happened

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that. So, is the "lst" full of data here at this code line "stTable.DataSource = lst;"?

Comment: Yes,u are right ,daniil

Comment: Full of data,availilable,butt not shown in my gridviev

Comment: Ok. Please post the Page Source.

Comment: should I create all gridview again when request raised??

Comment: danill ,I updated my question

Comment: I wanted to look at the Page Sources, i.e. the HTML rendered to a browser). In FireFox and Chrome you can press Ctrl+U to get it.

Comment: danilll,I checjk the source code and it seems that it shows the changes happened in the database.but I am confused,how come that happened or possiable.sources code shows correct data ,however User interface shows nothing change ??!

Comment: Hard to say what is going wrong. I need something runnable to test with.

Comment: I mean "need something runnable"

Comment: Just to be sure, you enabled the broker on the database right?
ALTER DATABASE [MyDataBase] SET ENABLE_BROKER

Comment: I have already done that.wait I simplified my question

Comment: I meant that I need something runnable from you. I need, probably, a test project which I can download, run and reproduce the problem. Thank you for posting the Page Sources. So, do you not see the data in the GridPanel? I executed the script and it appears to show the data correctly.

Comment: Dear daniil,as i mentioned my question,the problem is when any changes happen in database,grid must shows the new data automaticaly via triger the getdsta2 method.

Comment: updateed my question again daniil.

Comment: And when you are assigning new data source and rebinding your grid, does it actually call your databound event?

Comment: what u mean Allan "does it actually call your databound event",as u see my code bind it.like this  gridMasa.GetStore().DataSource = lst;
                gridMasa.GetStore().DataBind();

Comment: please try simple asp.net gridview for testing,same issue happen also ,asp gridview as well

Answer (score 7):

All the code you've shown is ASP.Net side code. The grid is shown on the client, is an HTML element. you need to notify the client of the change. HTTP refresh is not a trivial issue, you have to either:

- use a timer of the client and periodically poll for changes
- use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
- use [Server-Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (`Content-Type: text/event-stream`) but this is not supported by IE

Polling works but it can get taxing on the server, specially with large number of clients. There are countless examples of ASP.Net backed polling using Ajax.

WebSockets requires Windows 8/windows Server 2012 and IIS 8, see [Support for WebSockets Protocol](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097383)

You should probably also look into [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), which is an ASP.Net library specifically developer for pushing updates to the client.

As you can see, my answer does not even touch the topic of [Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/). Getting the notification from the DB to the ASP.Net middle tier is only one part of the equation, and `SqlDependency` is indeed the right answer. But you're completely missing the second part, the pushing of notification from mid-tier to the browser. You should only notify the browser that the update occurred and the client should refresh. Let the refresh load the data using the usual Page_load event. Use [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to server the page, this will automatically cache results and refresh *the cache* on any update.

Answer (score 1):

For an ASP.NET application you have to use the `SqlCacheDependency` class in name space `System.Web.Caching`; so you don't need the `OnChange` handler in this scenario.

This article explains how to implement SqlCacheDependency for an asp.net client:

[Query Notification using SqlDependency and SqlCacheDependency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-Sqlcach)

<strike>However, you have mentioned you are using SQL Server Express 2012 and according to page [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) and similar case in older SQl Server Express edition [Using Service Broker with Sql Server Express 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3559905/463478), since the SQL Server 2012 Express **does not support the broker service**, you will be **unable** to perform Query Notification in SQL Server 2012 Express.</strike>

Edit: this paragraph is incorrect (reckon due to the MSDN page on which is based being  misleading). Express editions support Service Broker and Query Notifications just fine, on all versions since SQL Server 2005. The 'Client Only' comment is better explained on the Express [SQL Server Express Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165636.aspx) page:

> SQL Server Express supports Service Broker, but **direct communication between two SQL Server Express servers** is not supported.

this restrictions does not affect Query Notifications.

These references are now merely informational [Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , [Creating a Query Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx) , [SqlDependency in an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: what is the OnNewMessage() ?! a fuction loading data?if so I ve already done this

Comment: @sakir Sorry, somehow I lost track your app is an asp.net client. I have corrected my answer.