# SqlDependency issue on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sqldependency

This part give me a error something like this,

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

here is the my code which raised when any changes happen on sql server.

```
     private void  dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
            {


System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");//raised error here
SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate);

            }
```

when I chech it with breakpoint,It can reach inside the  dependency_OnDataChangedDelegate but give me exception.

Comment: Why are you redirecting before working on the dependency object?

Comment: my original question here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592858/sqldependency-issue-with-the-asp-net . I want  rephresh the data when any changes happened on sql server.

Comment: but even those codes gave error.

Comment: First of all move the `Response.Redirect` on the last line, and then try to use `"~/Default.aspx"`. And as @Aristos this code might not work, as it might not be triggered by a request.

Comment: nope still give erro nilesh,doent matter where it is decribe

Answer (score 1):

The "**Object reference not set...**" on this line

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect
```

means that you call this function when the page is not available any more, probably you did not call this function from a page, but from a thread.

So the redirect did not know where to send their command, and this `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null, and you get that error.

Comment: should I describe this function anaother page??